# privoxy as reverse proxy for Linux server

Tags: linux, proxy, reverse-proxy, privoxy, transparentproxy

Im trying to set up privoxy as reverse proxy. I dont want to set up privoxy on each computer manualy but I want to set up it on server. I can't use transparent proxy as I need to block HTTPS too. So, is there any way to set up privoxy as reverse proxy?

Thanks for advices.

Comment: check this discussion, it might be helpful http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.privoxy.user/5534

Answer (score 1):

Point your browser to server:8118 in proxy settings of browser or set your w10 lan manual proxy configuration - windows flag-> type proxy-> manual proxy config
https://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/quickstart.html